# get data from ECU - issue with FD

Tags: python, can-bus

I'm trying to get information from the **ECU**. The connection works, and I see that the request has been sent but I don't receive any information. Because the application (which is burned in the unit and I work in front of it) checks that the **FD** **flag** exists and therefore I need it. I added the flag but it comes off, not received. In any case, I did not receive the information I requested. (I am using **VN5620** as a **CAN** Interface)

my code to **connection**:

```
# Create connection
bus = Bus(interface='vector', app_name='CANalyzer', channel=0, bitrate=250000, fd=True)

# Network layer addressing scheme
tp_addr = isotp.Address(isotp.AddressingMode.Normal_29bits, txid=0x1C440019, rxid=0x1C460019)

# Network/Transport layer (IsoTP protocol)
stack = isotp.CanStack(bus=bus, address=tp_addr, params=isotp_params)

# Speed First (do not sleep)
stack.set_sleep_timing(0, 0)

# Set up the ISO-TP connection using the appropriate CAN bus interface and parameters
tp_connection = PythonIsoTpConnection(stack)
```

my code to **request**:

```
with Client(tp_connection, request_timeout=1, config=config) as client:
    try:
        response = client.tester_present()
        if response.valid:
            # Extract the data from the response
            data = response.service_data.values[data_identifier]
            # Print the response data
            print(f"Response data: {data}")
        else:
            print("Error: Invalid response")
    finally:
        client.close()
```

the log:

```
2024-02-13 12:39:13 [INFO] Connection: Connection opened
2024-02-13 12:39:13 [INFO] UdsClient: TesterPresent<0x3e> - Sending TesterPresent request
2024-02-13 12:39:13 [DEBUG] Connection: Sending 2 bytes : [3e00]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\companion_chip_automation\Tests\UdsOnCanTest\tring_test.py", line 86, in <module>
    response = client.tester_present()
  File "C:\workspace\venv_3.8\lib\site-packages\udsoncan\client.py", line 174, in decorated
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\workspace\venv_3.8\lib\site-packages\udsoncan\client.py", line 391, in tester_present
    response = self.send_request(req)
  File "C:\workspace\venv_3.8\lib\site-packages\udsoncan\client.py", line 2184, in send_request
    raise TimeoutException('Did not receive response in time. %s time has expired (timeout=%.3f sec)' %
udsoncan.exceptions.TimeoutException: Did not receive response in time. Global request timeout time has expired (timeout=1.000 sec)
2024-02-13 12:39:14 [DEBUG] Connection: No data received: [TimeoutException] - Did not receive IsoTP frame from the Transport layer in time (timeout=1.0 sec)
2024-02-13 12:39:14 [ERROR] UdsClient: [TimeoutException] : Did not receive response in time. Global request timeout time has expired (timeout=1.000 sec)
```

Could you help me to get the first response and solve this issue?

Comment: print(bus.fd)  - the log is True, but to the application it's arrived False